# type mismatch converting string to date

Tags: vba

**Issue found: date language is in russian. Yet next question is - how can I convert the date string on go depending on dateformat of specific user?**

probably simple question. Smashing my head against the wall.

I have date in txt file and its being read as 01-Sep-21. Any action in VBA to work with it as date result in type mismatch - Datevalue, CDate, CLng - nothing is working. Where am I missing the issue?

test on raw input looks like this, it's not my code related issue (type mismatch on CDate):
[image]

upd:
01.09.2021 - works
01-09-2021 - works
09 replaced with Sep/September - doesnt work

Comment: CDate worked for me with the date you provided.  Perhaps you can post your code so we can help you better?

Comment: @Rosetta great, you're correct. But my laptop is in English, but it looks like dateformat is in Russian as "01-Сен-21" works. How can I work around it for code, as it's being used by multiple people. Can you convert on go depending on language?

Comment: Looking at your revised image, if you are dimming `DateProper` as Date, you do not need to call `CDate` on it... just set `DateProper = strDate`

Comment: You can format Date/Time for a specific language and country in VBA: https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=format-date-language-country-vba-access  explains this in good detail.

Answer (score 3):

`CDate` uses the current regional settings of the computer. If you need to parse dates in different locales, do so manually:

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VarDateFromStr Lib "OleAut32" (ByVal strIn As LongPtr, ByVal lcid As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByRef pdateOut As Date) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function VarDateFromStr Lib "OleAut32" (ByVal strIn As Long, ByVal lcid As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByRef pdateOut As Date) As Long
#End If
```

```vb
Const LANG_EN_US as Long = &H409&
Const LANG_RU_RU As Long = &H419&

Dim s As String
Dim d As Date

s = "21-Sep-2021"
VarDateFromStr StrPtr(s), LANG_EN_US, 0, d
Debug.Print d
  
s = "21-" & ChrW$(1057) & ChrW$(1077) & ChrW$(1085) & "-2021"  ' 21-Сен-2021
VarDateFromStr StrPtr(s), LANG_RU_RU, 0, d
Debug.Print d
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily change the date string to an actual date in VBA:

For example, in the image below you see that `strDate` is a `String` and `datDate` is a `Date`:

[image]